# Checking for duplicates Android sql using multiple columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I am needing to check for a duplicate record based on the information in multiple columns. I can get it to work if I am only using one column to check, but I am going to need it to check three columns, and if all three columns match, show a toast. The code below runs, but nothing is written to the db. If I remove two of the strings from the if statement, it works and writes to the db fine. I have tried using multiple cursors, but I get the same result when trying to check more than one column for duplicates.

```
private void saveState() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    eventDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

    String date = eventDate;
    String event = eventTitle.getText().toString();
    String empID = result;

    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllEntries();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    String enteredDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
    String enteredEvent = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("event"));
    String enteredEmpId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("empID"));

        if ( (enteredEmpId.equals(empID)) && (enteredDate.equals("date") && (enteredEvent.equals(event)))) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Employee has already been scanned for this event.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        } else {
            mDbHelper.createEntry(date, event, empID);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the fetchAllEntries() from my Helper class as well if needed:

```
public Cursor fetchAllEntries() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE,
            KEY_EVENT, KEY_EMPID}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

EDIT:
I got it to show the toast, but it is still writing to the db for some reason. I am also noticing the toast staying on the screen for a long time. I think it is because it is in the while loop and does not go off until it completes. I forgot to mention before, this app is scanning bar codes, so it needs to be able to recognize if they have been scanned already for the date and event when the scan take place. Here is the updated code

```
private void saveState() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    eventDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

    String date = eventDate;
    String event = eventTitle.getText().toString();
    String empID = result;

    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllEntries();

    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {

        mDbHelper.createEntry(date, event, empID);

    } else if (cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    String enteredDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
    String enteredEvent = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("event"));
    String enteredEmpId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("empID"));

         if ((enteredDate.equals(date)) && (enteredEvent.equals(event)) && (enteredEmpId.equals(empID))) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Employee has already been scanned for this event.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

        } else {

            mDbHelper.createEntry(date, event, empID);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check if more than 1 rows have same values:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE column1 = 'x' AND column2 = 'y' AND column3 = 'z'
```

if count exceeds 1, there are duplicates, get the id of first such row:

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE column1 = 'x' AND column2 = 'y' AND column3 = 'z' LIMIT 1
```

Now delete the rest of the rows:

```
DELETE * FROM myTable WHERE column1 = 'x' AND column2 = 'y' AND column3 = 'z' AND id != myId
```